# try to filter the records from the array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the array of objects and i am trying to show the records based upon some filtration,

I am doing in **VUE**

Here is my code

```
return this.system.filter(function (item, key) {
        if(key.)
      });
```

what i am tryin to achieve , if the key is: 1,2,3,4,5  it should be equal to 9 and display A because 9 is equal to A

because my keys are like this

```
this.system = [
 {
   key:0,"value:"x"
 },
{
   key:1,"value:"x1"
 },
{
   key:2,"value:"x2"
 },
{
   key:3,"value:"x3"
 },
{
   key:4,"value:"x4"
 },
{
   key:5,"value:"x5"
 },
{
   key:6,"value:"x6"
 },
{
   key:7,"value:"x7"
 },
{
   key:8,"value:"x8"
 },
{
   key:9,"value:"A"
 },
{
   key:10,"value:"B"
 },
{
   key:11,"value:"C"
 },
{
   key:12,"value:"D"
 },
]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: i alrady stated in my question

Comment: This statement is confusing: `if the key is: 1,2,3,4,5 it should be equal to 9`. The entries for those keys contain a value that is not equal to `9` (for instance, the entry for key `1` is `x1`), so why do you expect a value of 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      system: [{key:0,value:"x"}, {key:1,value:"x1"}, {key:2,value:"x2" }, {key:3,value:"x3"}, {key:4,value:"x4"}, {key:5,value:"x5"}, {key:6,value:"x6"}, {key:7,value:"x7"}, {key:8,value:"x8"}, {key:9,value:"A"}, {key:10,value:"B"}, {key:11,value:"C"}, {key:12,value:"D"},],
      chose: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    result() {
      return this.system.filter(item => {
        if (+this.chose > 0 && +this.chose < 6 || +this.chose === 9) {
          return item.key === 9
        } else {
          return item.key === +this.chose
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="chose" type="number" />
  {{ result }}
</div>
```

Comment: not all will return A, i mean that if the key selected is from 1 to 5, they will return me the value of 9 which is A, if they choose anything like key:10, the value of 11 will be returned which is C
@nikola

Comment: @Noah hey mate, check again pls,did I understood now? (just change chose variable and look result)

Comment: Thanks but i also need to hide those values to show in a dropdown  where i a using `<el-option
                        v-for="(item, key) in source"
                        :key="key"
                        :label="item.value"
                        :value="item.key"
                    >`

Comment: please see above comments

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to return value of `value` property based on the value of `key` property. If Yes, You can simply achieve that by using [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method. Here you go **:**

```js
const system = [
  {
    key:0,value:"x"
  },
  {
    key:1,value:"x1"
  },
  {
    key:2,value:"x2"
  },
  {
    key:3,value:"x3"
  },
  {
    key:4,value:"x4"
  },
  {
    key:5,value:"x5"
  },
  {
    key:6,value:"x6"
  },
  {
    key:7,value:"x7"
  },
  {
    key:8,value:"x8"
  },
  {
    key:9,value:"A"
  },
  {
    key:10,value:"B"
  },
  {
    key:11,value:"C"
  },
  {
    key:12,value:"D"
  }
];

const res = system.find(({key}) => key === 9);

console.log(res.value);
```